# Meteor cordova build fails because com.meteor.cordova-update.tgz is not found

Tags: android, cordova, curl, meteor

I've been trying to build a meteor cordova app for Android & iOS.
When I try to build only for iOS everything runs smoothly. 
After I add the Android platform and then run

`meteor build ~/builds --server myserver.meteor.com`

I get a very strange error:

`Error while building for mobile platforms: Error running curl
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   181    0   181    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
145      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   145
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /Users/idoivri/Sites/projects/alternative-tel-aviv/.meteor/local/cordo
Warning: va-build/local-plugins/com.meteor.cordova-update.tgz: No such file or
Warning: directory
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 833)`

And ideas what is com.meteor.cordova-update.tgz and why it seemingly causes errors in building the Android APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem probably derived from the changing nature of packages in Cordova, and my at-the-time Meteor version of 1.1.0.3.

Running `Meteor update` to bump version to 1.2 to solved the issue completely. In Meteor 1.2 the whole packaging of Cordova apps is re-done, according to Meteor's developers.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same issue, the difference being that it was iOS that wasn't working. Removing the cordova platform and resetting the project worked for me:

```
meteor remove-platform ios
meteor reset
meteor add-platform ios
```